# How to make jinja 2 display different divs if different options are selected

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```html
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2> Please select a sector you would like to iterate through:</h2>
<br />
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="statement" />
<input type="submit" />
Do you wish the output to be sorted?:
<select>
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>
</form>
{% if request.args.get['yes'] %}
dfghjhkl;nbovicudhbnrfmg,hklbjuvhcndmf,
{% elif request.args.get['no'] %}
12345676434565456765456
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

What I want is to display different information depending on what was selected within options. I just started Flask and Jinja2, so I am not so familiar with this type of coding.

Comment: And your question is? You are not using correct syntax, but presumably you got an error message? What would the expected output be?

Comment: Expected output is if Yes is selected in the option menu, then display ALPHA below, if selected item is No, display BETA below. There are no error messages what so ever

Comment: `request.args.get` is a function, not a list, so you're going to have to access it like `()` not `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is fairly unclear. Do you want it to dynamically happen? If so, then you would have to use JavaScript on the front end.

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myselect').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
  if(selected == "yes") $("#output").html("dfghjhkl;nbovicudhbnrfmg,hklbjuvhcndmf,");
  else $("#output").html("12345676434565456765456");
});
</script>
```

If you want to submit it and get a different page, change your form's action to `GET` and create a route to return your template and the `action` to a route that will do something like this:

```
@app.route("/yourform/getinfo")
def show_sorted_info():
  return render_template("results.html")
```

with the template for `results.html` being like this:

```
{% if request.args.get('yes') %}
  dfghjhkl;nbovicudhbnrfmg,hklbjuvhcndmf,
{% elif request.args.get('no') %}
  12345676434565456765456
{% else %}
  no option selected.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! Since I want it to dynamically happen, I will use JavaScript. But is it impossible to accomplish this task using only Jinja2 and Flask syntax?

Comment: not really. Gotta think of the pipeline of how Jinja works. When you send a template, Jinja2 will read all the blocks, and convert them into an HTML page and then give the HTML document to the front end.
So, that basically means that at the point it's rendered on the page, it's out of the back end's hands. If you want it to update dynamically, that's JavaScript's job.

Comment: Well, I used your code and got an error:
`ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
`Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.`

Comment: you don't have jQuery on your page then, you can include it in a tag like `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>`. If you don't want to use jQuery, you could do it with plain javascript, it will just be different in syntax

Answer (score 0):

If your form is using the "POST" method, then you have to inspect `request.form` instead of `request.args`. From the docs:

> #### form
>
> A MultiDict with the parsed form data from POST or PUT requests. Please keep in mind that file uploads will not end up here, but instead in the files attribute.
>
> #### args
>
> A MultiDict with the parsed contents of the query string. (The part in the URL after the question mark).

I guess you must either change the form method to "GET" or change the template code to use `request.form`.

Also, my Flask is a little rusty but I think it is `request.args.get('yes')` or `request.args['yes']` instead of `request.args.get['yes']`.